# C pointer and type conversion

Tags: c, pointers, casting

Need some help with type conversaion with string pointers in C. I have a function that gets the the `*argv` from main loop to pass command-line parameters to it. Since the parameters are fixed, I am trying to give my own `*argv` style parameter to it, but gcc everytime gives a warning:

```
passing argument 2 of ‘DirectFBInit’ from incompatible pointer type
```

Code:

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  ...
  char *argx[2] = {"self","--dfb:no-vt"};
  char *argxPtr = argx;

  DFBCHECK (DirectFBInit (&fakeArgc, &argxPtr));
  ...
}
```

I should mention that the function is manipulation argv (hence argx).

Here are the definition of `DirectFBInit`:

```
DFBResult DirectFBInit(
                     int         *argc,    /* pointer to main()'s argc */
                     char      *(*argv[])  /* pointer to main()'s argv */
                  );
```

The prog is running but I'm concerned about it.

Comment: char *argxPtr = argx; is not valid, can you show us the defintion of DirectFbInit

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] page soon.  We're not going to be able to help you with this until you provide the prototype for the `DirectFBInit()` function.  We could use Google to search for the information, but we shouldn't have to.  The chances are that you do not want the ampersands in front of the names in the call, but that's a guess.  It is a good idea to be concerned about such compiler warnings — they are important and the identified problems should be fixed.

Answer (score 3):

The web-site for [DirectFB](http://directfb.org/) probably has useful information.

Your code should probably be:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    ...
    char  *argvxData[] = { "self", "--dfb:no-vt", 0 };
    char **argvx       = argvxData;
    int    argcx       = 2;

    DFBCHECK(DirectFBInit(&argcx, &argvx));
    ...
}
```

Note the added null pointer to match the null pointer at `argv[argc]` in the `main()` program.  I've not read the manual to ensure that's required, but consistency is good.  When I checked the first edition of my answer, it did not compile without warnings — in fact, it got your warning; I've fixed that with the `argvxData` array and `argvx` double pointer.  The `[]` in the prototype is mostly a red-herring, but avoids accusations of being a [three-star programmer](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ThreeStarProgrammer).  It is equivalent to `char ***argv`.

Or you could pass the arguments to main:

```
    DFBCHECK(DirectFBInit(&argc, &argv));
```

Comment: thnx, tryed but it gives me that warning again (warning: passing argument 2 of ‘DirectFBInit’ from incompatible pointer type
). Passing from main does it without warning, but thats not what I want. Just to be claer: I do want to free the user from typing in options that dont need to be changed.

Comment: See update — I check-compiled and I've fixed the problem you and I both run into.  Note that if you do pass your own options, you deny the user the option of tweaking your DirectFB behaviour from their command line.  You may also find that errors reported by your program are prefixed with the name `self` instead of the actual name of your program.  To avoid that, you'd initialize `argvxData[0]` with `argv[0]`.

Comment: perfect, thats it. My c-fu is way too weak, spending hours without figuring it out. Thanks for your hint regarding user tweaking, but thats intended because its a embedded system. (Edit: vote +1)

Answer (score 1):

If we call `char *` "string" then that simplifies it a bit.  The function expects a pointer to an array of strings.  You are passing in a string, and an incorrectly-initialized string at that (`argx` has type `char*[]` but you are assigning it to a variable of type `char*`).

`&argxPtr` should actually be `&argx` (an expression of type `char*(*[])` as expected by the function), and you don't need `argxPtr` at all.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
int myargc = 2;
const char *myargv[] = { "self", "--dfb:no-vt" };
DirectFBInit(&myargc, &myargv);
```

Comment: thank you, but that doesnt remove the compiler warning regarding incompatible pointer type. Maybe it can be ignored but there is clearly a difference passing main's argv (no warning) vs the crafted argv (-> argx)

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to verify is to compile with -g and run gdb. Once in gdb, run the program, and type ptype and you will see the difference. I have replaced the func name with foo()

```
foo(int  *argc, char *(*argv[]))
{                               
}                               

int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{                            
    char *argx[2] = {"self","--dfb:no-vt"};
    char *argxPtr = argx;                  

    foo (&argc, &argxPtr);
}                              

(gdb) ptype foo
type = int (int *, char ***)

(gdb) ptype main
type = int (int, char **)
```

Hence the warning. Hope this helps.